# Declarative Jenkins + build in Docker + publish using Expo == connection refused

Tags: docker, jenkins, expo

While working with a simple declarative pipeline in Jenkins I'm running into an inconsistency where I can run the docker run commands manually to publish my expo project; however, when Jenkins creates the docker container and attempts to run the expo publish command I get a connection refused error. My initial guess was to add privileged to the docker container, then to ensure the user can run as root ... none of which actually helped. I'm curious if anyone has figured out how to run expo CI/CD inside of a docker container using Jenkins as the main way of facilitating that.

```
+ EXPO_DEBUG=true npx expo publish --non-interactive --release-channel develop
[07:50:24] Publishing to channel 'develop'...
[07:50:26] We noticed you did not build a standalone app with this SDK version and release channel before. Remember that OTA updates will not work with the app built with different SDK version and/or release channel. Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/publishing.html#limitations
[07:50:27] Building iOS bundle
[07:50:27] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
[07:50:27] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
```

My Jenkinsfile is pretty simple:

```
pipeline {
agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Dockerfile'
        }
    }
stages {
    stage('slack notification') {
        agent none
        steps {
            slackSend color: "good", message: "Build Started - ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>)"
        }
    }

    stage('run tests') {
        steps {
                sh 'cd /project && yarn test'
            }
    }

    stage ('publish to expo') {
        environment {
            expo_creds = credentials('expo_credentials')
        }
        steps {
            sh "npx expo login -u $expo_creds_USR -p $expo_creds_PSW && mv env.beta.ts env.ts && EXPO_DEBUG=true npx expo publish --non-interactive --release-channel ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
        }
    }
}

post {
    success {
        slackSend color: "good", message: "Build Finished - ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>) duration: ${currentBuild.durationString}"
    }
    unstable {
        slackSend color: "warning", message: "Build Unstable - ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>) duration: ${currentBuild.durationString}"
    }
    failure {
        slackSend color: "danger", message: "Build Failed - ${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} (<${env.BUILD_URL}|Open>) duration: ${currentBuild.durationString}"
    }
}
}
```

And my Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine as npm-dependencies
WORKDIR /project
RUN apk add --no-cache \
autoconf \
libtool \
automake \
g++ \
make \
libjpeg-turbo-dev \
libpng-dev \
libwebp-dev \
nasm
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY package.json .
COPY .npmrc .

RUN yarn install

FROM node:10.13-jessie
WORKDIR /project
COPY custom_types ./custom_typess
COPY img ./img
COPY assets ./assets
COPY src ./src
COPY tests ./tests
COPY babel.config.js ./
COPY .buckconfig ./
COPY .flowconfig ./
COPY .watchmanconfig ./
COPY app.json .
COPY App.js .
COPY env.docker.ts ./env.ts
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY package.json .
COPY jest.config.js .


COPY --from=npm-dependencies /project/node_modules /project/node_modules
RUN npm install -g expo-cli
RUN mkdir /.npm && chmod 0777 /.npm
RUN mkdir /.cache && chmod 0777 /.cache
RUN mkdir /.yarn && chmod 0777 /.yarn
RUN mkdir /.expo && chmod 0777 /.expo
RUN mkdir /project/.expo && chmod 0777 /project/.expo
```

Comment: Is your Jenkins running inside of it's own docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is really just expo specific and is probably a bug in how it's made. After doing the login step I manually cd'd into the /project directory and then rm -rf .expo.

setting the CWD to /project and then deleting .expo fixes the issue. why it worked outside of jenkins but not inside is still a bit befuddling; however, the combination of those two actions resolved it for me.